# what is the architecture of a wireless communication? Please explain patiently

Tags: frequency, communication, digital-communications, modulation, ofdm

Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiple Access (OFDMA) and Frequency Shift Keying(FSK).

Hey, I'm extremely confused with the gigantic number of modulation schemes out there. Please help.

I understand how FSK/ASK/AM/FM works. It's simple. But am not able to wrap my mind around OFDMA.

I again understand FDMA, where the available bandwidth is divided into frequencies and given out with guard bands. This can be combined with TDMA to accommodate more customers. As in, time multiplexing the divided frequencies.
[image]

I believe the architecture is like this data>keying(Modulation)>multiple access schemes>transmission. Is this right?

Suppose I have a message say "Apple is red" which I need to send through my laptop to a device on the network.

My laptop will encode it into binary>then into a common code the channel supports-for more efficiency > Space is left between each word/null symbols to differentiate?(Explain please)> Then this is modulated using digital keying techniques like say-FSK > Multiple access scheme like TDMA/FDMA/OFDMA are applied? ( Explain please) > Then transmitted

Another question is does the media access control-CSMA/CA, Carrier Sense Multiple Access come **inside** each slot divided by the multiple access scheme? like say we use FDMA in combination with TDMA, Does the CSMA/CA come in each of the time slot?

Sorry if I messed everything up. Please explain.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We like one question per post; you should move yours about CSMA/CA to another question.

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose I have a message say "Apple is red" which I need to send through my laptop to a device on the network.
> My laptop will encode it into binary>then into a common code the channel supports-for more efficiency > Space is left between each word/null symbols to differentiate?(Explain please)> Then this is modulated using digital keying techniques like say-FSK > Multiple access scheme like TDMA/FDMA/OFDMA are applied? ( Explain please) > Then transmitted

It's far more simple, or complicated than that. You appear to be trying to hold the whole top to bottom communications architecture in your head in one go, and that's impossible for any human. Developers don't do it, and neither should you.

- It's simpler than that

The laptop wants to send a message to a device on the network? No. An application running on the laptop wants to send a message to an application running on a network device. The two applications use a message passing service, which is also running on the laptop and the other network device. What does the message passing service do? It passes messages, you don't have to worry about any more than that. Does the message pass over a cable, or the air, in binary or morse code or carrier pigeon? It doesn't matter, the message passing service uses whatever connectivity service there is below it.

- It's more complicated than that

As you go down the stack, your message passes through (not necessarily in this order) services that maintain the network connection in the event of rerouting, know physical addresses for network devices, break long messages up into short messages, label and error protect short messages, reassemble long messages and ask for retransmission of any lost short messages.

Eventually you get down to the physical layer, that actual modulates and demodulates RF.

FDMA is an inefficient way of spreading data across a bandwidth, using guard bands and conventional filters. OFDMA is an efficient way of spreading data across a bandwidth, using FFTs to implement filters with no guard bands.

Comment: I know how network stack works. I am concerned only with the physical layer. Please explain that part.

Comment: @VishwaMithraTatta *Please explain that part.* What is preventing you from reading a book about that? And as mentioned in this answer: stop trying to understand **everything in detail** in one go. It's not gonna happen.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I did read the book. That's why I'm still confused. I just wanna know if the multiple access comes right after the modulation of the message.

Comment: @VishwaMithraTatta If you knew about the network stack, you wouldn't ask a question about the physical layer beginning at the 'apple is red' message from your laptop. Multiple access comes well above modulation in the stack.

Comment: *I just wanna know if the multiple access comes right after the modulation of the message* **No**, they're separate things and unrelated.

Comment: @Neil_UK you want me to ask from "there are 3 frames to be sent"?

Comment: Seriously, stop trying to pick a fight and just tell me if multiplexing happens right after the keying-modulation. Please.

Comment: @VishwaMithraTatta `you want me to ask from "there are 3 frames to be sent"?` That is the sort of context that allows us to understand what you know, and figure out your area of misunderstanding, so we can answer your true problem. Starting at the 'apples' simply suggested confusion about the whole process.

Comment: 'multiplexing' is a word that can apply in several places, and now sounds different to your 'multiple access' question. Pick one modulation scheme, ask one question, rinse and repeat as necessary.